# Mongoid and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

How do I store an array data in `mongoDB` and later fetch it and print? I am using mongoid gem in ruby:

tweet.rb

```
class Tweet    
    include Mongoid::Document        
    field :id, type: Integer        
    field :text, type: String        
end
```

I am storing in database like this:

```
Tweet.new(id: tweet.id, text: tweet.text)
```

Is this thee right way and how to retrieve and show from db?

**`Edit`**

The command line showed up this error:

> [2014-03-29 13:06:17] ERROR bad Request-Line `:\x00\x00\x00?]\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0
>   0\x00?\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00admin.$cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00????\x13\x00\x00\x
>   00\x10ismaster\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'.
>   [2014-03-29 13:06:17] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
>   borted by the software in your host machine.
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`write'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `<<'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`_write_data'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:i
>   n `send_body_string'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:i
>   n`send_body'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:i
>   n `send_response'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in`
>   run'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `blo
>   ck in start_thread'
>   [2014-03-29 13:06:37] ERROR bad Request-Line`:\x00\x00\x00?]\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0
>   0\x00?\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00admin.$cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00????\x13\x00\x00\x
>   00\x10ismaster\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'.
>   [2014-03-29 13:06:37] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
>   borted by the software in your host machine.
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `write'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`<<'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `_write_data'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:i
>   n`send_body_string'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:i
>   n `send_body'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:i
>   n`send_response'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in
>   `run'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`blo
>   ck in start_thread'
>   [2014-03-29 13:06:57] ERROR bad Request-Line `:\x00\x00\x00\x04^\x01\x00\x00\x00
>   \x00\x00?\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00admin.$cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00????\x13\x00\x0
>   0\x00\x10ismaster\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'.
>   [2014-03-29 13:06:57] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
>   borted by the software in your host machine.
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`write'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `<<'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`_write_data'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:i
>   n `send_body_string'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:i
>   n`send_body'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:i
>   n `send_response'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in`
>   run'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `blo
>   ck in start_thread'
>   [2014-03-29 13:07:17] ERROR bad Request-Line`:\x00\x00\x00\x1D^\x01\x00\x00\x00
>   \x00\x00?\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00admin.$cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00????\x13\x00\x0
>   0\x00\x10ismaster\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'.
>   [2014-03-29 13:07:17] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
>   borted by the software in your host machine.
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `write'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`<<'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `_write_data'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:i
>   n`send_body_string'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:i
>   n `send_body'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:i
>   n`send_response'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in
>   `run'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`blo
>   ck in start_thread'
>   [2014-03-29 13:07:37] ERROR bad Request-Line `:\x00\x00\x006^\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0
>   0\x00?\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00admin.$cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00????\x13\x00\x00\x
>   00\x10ismaster\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'.
>   [2014-03-29 13:07:37] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
>   borted by the software in your host machine.
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`write'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `<<'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`_write_data'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:i
>   n `send_body_string'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:i
>   n`send_body'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:i
>   n `send_response'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in`
>   run'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `blo
>   ck in start_thread'
>   [2014-03-29 13:07:57] ERROR bad Request-Line`:\x00\x00\x00O^\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0
>   0\x00?\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00admin.$cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00????\x13\x00\x00\x
>   00\x10ismaster\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'.
>   [2014-03-29 13:07:57] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a
>   borted by the software in your host machine.
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `write'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`<<'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `_write_data'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:i
>   n`send_body_string'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:i
>   n `send_body'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:i
>   n`send_response'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in
>   `run'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in`blo
>   ck in start_thread'

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

You cannot declare an "id" field on your model; this happens when you include Mongoid::Document.

Also, calling #new will create the object within your application, but will not write it to the database. Here's what your code should be:

tweet.rb

```
class Tweet
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :text, type: String
end
```

Creating a new tweet:

```
tweet = Tweet.new(text: "Ipsum Lorem") # This does not write to the database
tweet.save # This writes the tweet to the database
```

Retrieving a tweet:

```
tweet = Tweet.find_by(text: "Ipsum Lorem")
```

Saving a tweet:

```
tweet = Tweet.find_by(text: "Ipsum Lorem")
tweet.text = "New text!"
tweet.save
# OR
Tweet.find_by(text: "Ipsum Lorem").update_attribute(:text, "Some new text")
```

Mongoid is super flexible. There are many ways to save and retrieve information from the database. I'd recommend that you peruse [the mongoid docs here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/).

Edit: If you need to have the id field sequential, [there's a gem for that.](https://github.com/goncalossilva/mongoid-sequence)

Comment: It showed an error indicating: 
Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:44002572 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address=nil>]>

Comment: Okay..that means something funky is going on with your DB. If you have not already, run the command "rails g mongoid:install". Also, make sure your database is running. Normally the "rails s" command would take care of this, but since you are not using ActiveRecord, you'll need to ensure that your mongodb is already running before launching the server.